# Powershell $? variable not behaving as expected

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a script I use to create mailboxes. I just discovered that my error handling is not working as expected.

```
Write-Host "Attempting to create mailbox."
[void](Enable-Mailbox johndoe `
    -DisplayName "Doe,John" `
    -Alias johndoe `
    -RetentionPolicy 'Custom Retention Policy' `
    -ActiveSyncMailboxPolicy 'Default')
if($?){
    Write-Host "User & mailbox created"; Write-Host}
else{
    Write-Host "Error creating user/mailbox" -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Yellow
    exit}
Add-MailboxPermission -Identity johndoe -User 'DOMAIN\ExchangeFullAdmins' -AccessRights 'FullAccess'
if($?){
    Write-Host "Permissions set on mailbox"; Write-Host}
else{
    Write-Host "Error setting ExchangeFullAdmins permissions on mailbox" -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Yellow
exit}
```

If there is an error creating the mailbox, the first `if($?)` evaluates as `$true` and the second one evaluates as `$false` (since there's no mailbox to act on). I expect both to evaluate as `$false`. Any ideas why the first one isn't firing off correctly?

These are the errors generated by each command:

```
Enable-Mailbox : Unable to generate the e-mail address. Unable to load address module 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Excha
nge Server\V14\Mailbox\address\SMTP\AMD64\inproxy.dll' for address type 'SMTP'. Additional message: 'Access is denied'.
At \\server\share\temp.ps1:2 char:22
+ [void](Enable-Mailbox <<<<  johndoe `
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (0:Int32) [Enable-Mailbox], RusException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 385E7D70,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.EnableMailbox

Add-MailboxPermission : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Identity' because it is null.
At \\server\share\temp.ps1:13 char:33
+     Add-MailboxPermission -Identity <<<<  johndoe -User 'DOMAIN\ExchangeFullAdmins' -AccessRights 'FullAccess'
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-MailboxPermission], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTa
   sks.AddMailboxPermission
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think because type-casting is successful. Remove `[void]` and try again.

If it works, then you could try instead of `[void]` piping to `Out-Null` and see whether you get an error:

`` Enable-Mailbox johndoe `
    -DisplayName "Doe,John" `
    -Alias johndoe `
    -RetentionPolicy 'Custom Retention Policy' `
    -ActiveSyncMailboxPolicy 'Default' | Out-Null ``

Comment: That's exactly what it was.

I had removed the `[void]` at one point during troubleshooting but I wasn't testing the right combination of circumstances to see that it was indeed the problem. Removing that and using `Out-Null` does exactly what I expect.